# Galaxy s5 Neo. Screen comes on intermittently

Tags: screen

(May 14, 2017) In the last week or so, whether my phone is plugged in or not, the phone will just wake up the screen will come on. When this happens, there are no notifications coming in at the time. If I'm in lock screen, the screen will stay on for a short while and if the phone was unlocked at the time, the screen will stay on for as long as I have my screen duration set for. This is obviously a problem as it is draining my battery. While typing this post, it has happened twice. I've deleted any recent apps I've downloaded with no change. There has been a lot of Google updates lately and I suspect one of them is causing this - or - my phone is physically damaged (I am a bit rough with it)

I have ESET Mobile security installed and a scan shows no viruses. My app list is fairly short: beyond the standard apps, I have a Craigslist app, a CraveTV app, Relay for reddit, Netflix, Nova Launcher, Roboform, an SMS Backup app and Zedge.

I would love to hear a few suggestions to try!

Edit :  I downloaded a phone cleaner and discovered an app was still installed (but didn't appear in google play store > my apps) and it was running. It is called Easyconnect (for mirroring phone to the car). Interestingly, it required me to go into developer options and turn USB debugging on. I had uninstalled that app two days ago! I'm wondering if this not be the perpetrator. I'll let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with my S5 active. There was no immediate fix, but I was pretty sure it was caused by networks being found. I never saw it happen when I had wi-fi turned off, but I never really confirmed that this was the issue.

Also I had a friend who found 'Air wake up' was on, which was being triggered even without waving anything in front of the screen. So maybe check that.

Comment: Thanks. I looked just now and couldn't find an option for Air Wake Up. I'll turn off my WiFi and see if it helps.